# Iterate Nonetype object

Tags: python, object, nonetype

i want go deep with some statistic data, and i write some code.

```
import urllib2
import HTMLParser

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=MCESTUS1&f=M')
data = response.read()


class TableParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.in_td = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'td':
            self.in_td = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_td:
            print data

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.in_td = False

p = TableParser()
raw_data = p.feed(data)

 raw_list = []
 for string in raw_data:
     raw_list.append(string)

 print raw_list
```

Some output from this script/

```
2015
421,472
448,039
474,815
483,379
479,335
469,539
455,470
457,810
460,786
486,700

-
Release Date: 12/31/2015
Next Release Date: 1/29/2016
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FirstData.py", line 28, in <module>
    for string in raw_data:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

That work, but i cant iterate through the Nonetype object, that first.

And second how i can put this data in the pandas for some graph with month and quantity?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the parser parses but you need to get the data out of the parser via some other method than the return value of `p.feed(data)` as that is always going to be `None`. How about accumulating it in a list that is a property of the parser object:

```
import urllib2
import HTMLParser

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=MCESTUS1&f=M')
data = response.read()


class TableParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.in_td = False
        self.raw_data = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'td':
            self.in_td = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_td:
            print data
            self.raw_data.append(data)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.in_td = False

p = TableParser()
p.feed(data)

print p.raw_data
```

Untested.